# Nuxt 3 Axios and Fetch API keeps on getting canceled for no reason

Tags: axios, fetch, nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxt3

I am using Nuxt 3.
I am using both Axios and Fetch API.
I use Axios for Laravel APIs
I use Fetch API for Nuxt 3 server apis.

This was working 2 days ago. But for some reason, both of it seems to inconsistently getting canceled for no reason at all. And I could not even trace where it is coming from. Sometimes, post requests gets through the backend right after it was canceled and sometimes not.
[image]

It is also happening on other requests and it is inconsistent but often.
I do not know where to start looking or how I would construct this question cause, literally, I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days now. I tried cherry picking commits from before this started happening, but it is still doing the same thing.

My suspect is after Nuxt 3 got updated from 3.3.2 to 3.4.1. But like I said, I already tried cherry picking but it was still persistent. I also removed `node_modules` folder and ran a clean install of packages. But still the same thing. Sometimes it gets canceled, sometimes not, but most of the time canceled.

I just need guidance on where to start looking.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue with Nuxt3 + Supabase

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not related, but I was having the same problem but instead I was using `useFetch` composable of Nuxt3. The values of `url` and `options` are watched by default so, it not necessary to call *.refresh() or *.execute(). If you do, then your are duplicating the calls.

Some github issue related to the problem: [Issue 18453](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/18453)